# Cannot update a Firestore's document after a purchase verification using Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, in-app-purchase, google-cloud-functions

I've been working on a function to verify purchase in server side. Everything works well.
Only one issue, when the purchase is valid (the response.status === 200) the console shows (success) but the document hasn't been updated.
Here is my code. Did i miss something ?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const publisher = google.androidpublisher('v2');
const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
   email: 'my_email',
   key: 'my_key',
   scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
});

admin.initializeApp();
admin.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

exports.validatePurchases = functions.firestore
.document('purchases/{channel}')
.onCreate((docSnapshot, context) => {
    const purchase = docSnapshot.data();
    const order_id = purchase.orderId;
    const package_name = purchase.packageName;
    const sku = purchase.sku;
    const purchase_token = purchase.purchaseToken;
    const user_id = purchase.userId;

    authClient.authorize((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        publisher.purchases.subscriptions.get({
            auth: authClient,
            packageName: package_name,
            subscriptionId: sku,
            token: purchase_token
        }, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            // Result Status must be equals to 200 so that the purchase is valid
            if (response.status === 200) {
                console.log('success');
                return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_id).update({
                    purchaseToken: purchase_token,
                    isPremiumS: 'true'
                });                    
            } else {
                console.log('fail');
                return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_id).update({
                    purchaseToken: purchase_token,
                    isPremiumS: 'false'
                });                    
            }
        });
    });
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Did you check if `user_id` isn't null?

Comment: Yes i checked it, it's not null.

Comment: Try add .catch block and see if there are errors thrown.  `return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_id).update({
                    purchaseToken: purchase_token,
                    isPremiumS: 'true'
                }).catch(error => { ... })`

Comment: ok, i will try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `null`, your function should return the `Promise` from your Firestore `update()` calls.

Add `return` in two places:

```
  return authClient.authorize((err, result) => {...

  return publisher.purchases.subscriptions.get({...
```

Delete `return null;` at the end of the function

Comment: I tried your solution, i got this error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Comment: i noticed also that after displaying this error the console shows also the 'success' message (after some minutes as the original problem) and without updating the document.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest.  I'm not familiar with the googleapis you're using and can't find the reference docs.  Do you mind updating the question to show your changes so I can confirm you understood my instructions correctly?

Comment: I followed your instruction but as i told you i got the above error. I'm not familiar too with this api. Anyway thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: solved ! instead of returning authClient.authorize, i returned a new Promise :        return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{                                      authClient.authorize((err, result) => {