# Will Firebase's policy of (user-selected) Cloud Firestore location unchangeable per project be possibly changed in the future?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, location, fixed, policy

I am new to app development and Firebase. After satisfactorily developing my apps in Android Studio and happily experimenting one with Firebase Firestore and Cloud Functions, I realize to my horror that I have selected the Cloud Firestore location as US-Central, which is far from the base of my targeted Thai users.

I do not want to lose the Project Name or ID forever, so I would like to ask if it is at least technologically and economically possible that Firebase will allow re-selecting of Cloud Firestore location in the future.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly for questions like this.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @DougStevenson Can your look at [this question from earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687857/4815718)?  My answer didn't work.  Apologies, Patcharawee, for piggy-backing on your question.  I didn't know how else to send a message to Doug.

Comment: No problem, @BobSnyder; be my guest!